# Is the book "Anyone Can Easily PK" by Punitto Moe real, or does it only exist in Overlord?

Tags: overlord

In episode 8 of the anime [Overlord](http://myanimelist.net/anime/29803/Overlord/), ~10:37, Momonga/Ains refers to a book "Anyone Can Easily PK" by Punitto Moe.  Is that book a fictional work, or is it a real work?

In other words, does this book exist in the real world (i.e. for use with MMORPGS such as World of Warcraft, Guild Wars, et al), or is it something that only exists within the Overlord anime/manga universe?

Comment: Yep, this is correct tagging. Generally speaking, the series title should be used, although sometimes other tags (e.g. [tag:tropes]) may also be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking through multiple book sites and also just typing in the author it seems that it is only a fictional work for the series. Reading the character bio for *[Punitto Moe](http://overlordmaruyama.wikia.com/wiki/Punitto_Moe)* it states:

> He created the basics of "Anyone Can Easily PK" for Ainz Ooal Gown which includes taking drastic measures to learn as much information about the target player as possible when doing Player Kills, as well as maintaining a constant discretion from the target player.